# Joomla tooltip showing < br /> tags issue

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

I got a little annoying issue about joomla tooltips for 'Edit Article' button in frontend showing  < br /> tags inside them instead of creating line breaks.

Not sure what's causing this tooltip issue?
This seems to occur on all my joomla sites, included a fresh  one running in Protostar template.
So I don't know if it's a common issue?

Does anyone know of a fix to solve it so that the tooltip will show correctly.

So that instead of showing:
Published< br />Day, dd-mm-YYYY< br />Written by Author

It is to show like this:
Published
Day,month,year
Written by Author

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340802/add-line-break-within-tooltips and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502054/web-tooltip-universally-accepted-linebreak-character

Comment: @Hammur, you now have the privilege to vote in our current moderator [election](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).  Please exercise your new democratic privilege.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is an issue with Joomla itself and not your fault, therefore the best thing to do would be to post an issue on the [Github Issue Tracker](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues) for the Joomla CMS so it may get fixed in the next update.

Once done, hopefully someone will create a PR for the issue and/or a temporary fix.

Comment: I guessed it had to be something with Joomla itself, but was hoping someone here knew of a fix for it. I will try posting it on Github as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a link to the bootstrap.min.js in the modules default.php and that should fix it.  I had the same issue with the .tooltips and this fixed my issue.